# jQuery passing $(this) into setTimeout fn - What am I missing?

Tags: jquery, settimeout

This has to be easy, but I can't see it. Need another (smarter) pair of eyes.

This works:

```
$('#topmenu li').hover(
    function(){
        $this = $(this);
        alert( $this.attr('id') );
    }
);
```

And this works:

```
$('#topmenu li').hover(
    function(){
        $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function($this){
            alert( 'hello' );
        },800);
    }
);
```

But this does not work:

```
$('#topmenu li').hover(
    function(){
        $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function($this){
            alert( $this.attr('id') );
        },800);
    }
);
```

What am I missing??

Comment: try `setTimeout(function(){
            alert( $this.attr('id') );
        },800);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that adding a parameter to the function creates a local variable in its private scope, which is likely to mask other variables with the same name in one of the parents scopes.

Without a parameter :

```
var $this = 1;
function f() {
    return $this;
}
f(); // 1
```

With a parameter :

```
var $this = 1;
function f($this) {
    return $this;
}
f(); // undefined
f(2); // 2
$this; // 1
```

In the first case, there is no `$this` variable in the function's scope, so, the globally defined `$this` variable is returned. In the second case, `f()` returns `undefined` because `$this` exists locally, but is set to `undefined` by default, while `f(2)` returns `2` because the local `$this` is set to `2`.

Regarding your own situation, `$this.attr('id')` will crash because `$this` is not defined. You have to replace `setTimeout(function($this){` with `setTimeout(function(){` in order to retrieve the outer variable.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation (very much) but I don't understand this point: why is $this (a jQuery object) available inside the function without it being passed INTO the function? It isn't a global...? Also, how WOULD one pass the jQuery object into the function? Or is the answer because the 2nd function is inside the 1st function?

Comment: @gibberish Right, the inner function inherits from the scope of the outer function (from all surrounding scopes actually, including the global scope). So, there is no need to pass the variable to the inner function since it's already available in the outer function. This is what my first code block tells. For that matter, you should make some experiments around this topic into your browser console (F12 > copy-paste > ENTER). Here is an article which might be a better help, hopefully : http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html.

Comment: I don't know why I had not accepted a correct answer to this question. Fortunately, someone downvoted the question today and I was brought back here. FINALLY... I have done right by your answer. Sorry for my ... (the irony of this kills me...) *procrastination*...

Comment: Thank you @gibberish! I apreciate the nice comment :-)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `$this` from [`setTimeout` callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#Callback_arguments)

```
$('#topmenu li').hover(
    function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
            alert( $this.attr('id') );
        },800);
    }
);
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/gL35t/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass `$this` as paramter in `setTimeout` function

```
$('#topmenu li').hover(
    function(){
        $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
            alert( $this.attr('id') );
        },800);
    }
);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/uX5J8/)